# How to perform arithmetic operation between the datavariable accessing value and the integer value in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to add the two values in c# one is the integer value and another is the variable that can return the integer value and i want to perform addition operation and return the value... upto now i have used the following code:

```
lbl_Am.Text = Application["Amount"].ToString();
```

this will returns the integer value and i want to add the above returned value with some integer value ex..int 2;

how can i do this addition operation and store it in another variable using c#?

Comment: What type does `Application["Amount"]` have (without calling the `ToString()`)? Maybe you can simply say `int i = 2; var sum = Application["Amount"] + i;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int result = Convert.ToInt32(Application["Amount"]) + 2;
```

Comment: Great - click the accept answer tick just to the left of here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
int Amt;
int.TryParse(lbl_Am.Text,out Amt);
```

Now you can Add

```
var AddedAmt = Amt + <Other Integer>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is unclear, but if you intend to perform math operations to a string you'd better make sure the string actually represents a number:

```
var value = Application["Amount"].ToString();
int intvalue = 0;

if (int.TryParse(value, out intvalue)
{
   var newvalue = intvalue + 2;
}

//whatever you want to do with the newvalue
```